# What is the meaning of this kubernetes UI error message?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running 3 ubuntu server VMs on my local machine and trying to manage with kubernetes.

The UI does not start by itself when using the start script, so I tried to start up the UI manually using:

`kubectl create -f addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-rc.yaml --namespace=kube-system
kubectl create -f addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-svc.yaml --namespace=kube-system`

The first command succeeds then I get the following for the second command:

> error validating "addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-svc.yaml": error validating
>   data: [field nodePort: is required, field port: is required]; if you
>   choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with
>   --validate=false

So I try editing the default kube-ui-scv file by adding nodePort to the config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-ui
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-ui
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "KubeUI"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-ui
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30555
```

But then I get another error after the edit or adding in nodePort:

> The Service "kube-ui" is invalid. spec.ports[0].nodePort: invalid
>   value '30555': cannot specify a node port with services of type
>   ClusterIP

I cannot get the ui running at my master nodes IP. `kubectl get nodes` returns correct information. Thanks.

Comment: this works okay for me.  What instructions did you follow to setup your cluster and what version does `kubectl version` print?

Comment: also, what happened if you did `kubectl create -f addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-svc.yaml --namespace=kube-system --validate=false` using the original, unedited yaml file?

Comment: @EricTune when i use the unedited version I get the first error I posted above. My version output is: `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2+", GitVersion:"v1.2.0-alpha.1.1067+b9c7cf43b291e7-dirty", GitCommit:"b9c7cf43b291e7aafec371d86108f924b89e4df2", GitTreeState:"dirty"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}`

Comment: @EricTune i used this tutorial: http://containertutorials.com/get_started_kubernetes/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're running into https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8901 with the first error, can you set it to 0? Setting NodePort with a service.Type=ClusterIP doesn't make sense, so the second error is legit.